# Icons in Custom jQuery Mobile Select Menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using a custom select menu from jQuery Mobile, and I'd like to put icons into the custom pop-up menu to accompany each `option`.  I'm applying the `data-icon` attribute to each `option`, like so:

```
<select name='mySelect' id='mySelect' data-icon='gear'>
    <option value='0' data-icon='star'>Option 0</option>
    <option value='1' data-icon='star'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2' data-icon='star' selected="selected">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

FWIW, I've already verified that my custom icons work in the select button itself.  Am I just completely wrong in expecting icons to appear in the custom menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported by default but here is a quick piece of code to make it possible:

```
//wait for the correct page to initialize
$(document).delegate('#home', 'pageinit', function () {

    //loop through each of the SELECT elements in this page
    $.each($(this).find('select'), function () {

        //get the ID of this select because it's menu's ID is based off of it
        var currentID = this.id;

        //iterate through each of the OPTION elements for this SELECT element
        $.each($(this).find('option'), function (index, element) {

            //if the OPTION element has the `data-icon` attribute
            if ($(element).attr('data-icon') != undefined) {

                //update the menu for this SELECT by adding an icon SPAN element
                //to each of the OPTION elements that has a `data-icon` attribute
                $('#' + currentID + '-menu').children().eq(index).find('.ui-btn-inner').append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-' + $(element).attr('data-icon') + ' ui-icon-shadow" />');
            }
        });
    });
});​​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NHQGD/

Comment: This is kind of what I was afraid of...  Where's the feature request form? =)

Comment: That's a pretty tiny plugin, `336 bytes minified`.

Comment: Yes, it's tiny, but it doesn't cover all the bases: `data-iconpos`, for instance.  Also doesn't handle calling `selectmenu()` or triggering `create` on dynamic content.  Not that I expect that from an SO answer, but you get my drift, I'm sure =)

Comment: No, it's the basic idea, there for you to flesh-out as necessary.

Comment: what if I dont have data-icon on each option ? I'm getting the values of the Select Menu from server side.

Comment: @Zakos You've got options. 1) If the JS is inline on the dynamic page, then you can just "hard-code" the icon into the correct place in the JS. 2) If your JS needs to be external or can't be built dynamically, you can save the data you want as a `data-attribute` on some element (e.g. the `body` element) or in a hidden form input and then read that value in the JS.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I'v tried for many hours and failed , Iv tried something like var 'zakos = $('#zakosList-menu');' but then I'm stuck on how to get to each option and add it the